# I boot to a grub prompt. How can I fix this?

Tags: grub2, kubuntu

I duel boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04. I tried to install kubuntu over an installation I had of Ubuntu.  However, the installer crashed in the middle of the actual installation process. Afterwards my computer froze. I decided to shut down my computer, which was all I could do at the moment anyway.  Now when I start up my computer it boots to a grub prompt. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Press the `Boot Menu` option F-Key during the BIOS boot and choose `Windows`

On my Dell laptop, it's the `F12` key. Otherwise, you can press the `Menu` key (`F2` on the Dell) and arrange your boot order to Windows first.

Comment: Thanks, that let me boot into Windows fine. Would you happen to know by any chance how I can fix my grub permanently? Could re-installing kubuntu fix it?

Comment: Look up "Grub Repair" and see what that says.  I don't know, but I did discover that if I install Ubuntu on a flash drive, it fixed my boot problems to my Ubuntu on my main HDD one time.    You could try re-installing Kubuntu, or install it elsewhere.  

I have been running W10 on my Laptop, and when I get it backed up well, I'm going to try to dual-boot it with Ubuntu.

Comment: BTW, I discovered that when it is installed, Grub allows you to choose Linux or Windows.  So, you can re-order Windows and Buntu to the order you prefer and keep using Grub. It'll automatically boot the default if left a few seconds.  I set mine to 2 seconds.  If I am interested in changing, I'll be there to catch it.